# Most appropriate way to extract a array of matrices from an array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

New user to numpy. I have a question for which I did not find a solution not involving a raw loop.

I have an 1D array of size N * M. Every block of size M is composed of a flat matrix and some additional values. I want to extract thoses matrices.

For the example, let us consider a 1D array of the form:

```
[a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 f2 g2 .... aN bN cN dN eN fN gN]
```

What would be the most elegant and/or efficient way to build the following array of N 2*2 matrices:

```
[[[a1,b1],
  [c1,d1]],
 [[a2,b2],
  [c2,d2]],
 ....
 [[aN,bN],
  [cN,dN]]]
```

Note that e1 f1 g1 have been discarded.

As a concrete example, consider:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,-1,-1,-1
              0,1,2,3,-1,-1,-1])
```

The expected result shall be an array containing two matrices [[0,1],[2,3]]

Comment: What does `np.reshape(arr, (-1,2,2))` do for you?

Comment: Does not seem to work. See the example.

Comment: Try some variations on the reshape and call us in the morning!  You might also need to take a slice of the resulting array.

Comment: Well, I tried (a lot) before posting. I did not find a way to skip the e0, f0, etc... Maybe I missed some useful features...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution seems to use the `as_strided` function.

Let `b` be the block size, the following works:

```
y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(x.size // b,2,2),
                                    strides=(x.strides[0]*b,
                                             x.strides[0]*2,
                                             x.strides[0]))
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0,1,2,3,-1,-1,-1,
...               0,1,2,3,-1,-1,-1,
...               0,1,2,3,-1,-1,-1])
>>> b = 7
>>> y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(x.size // b,2,2),
...                                         strides=(x.strides[0]*b,
...                                                  x.strides[0]*2,
...                                                  x.strides[0]))
>>> print(y)
[[[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[0 1]
  [2 3]]

 [[0 1]
  [2 3]]]
```

If anyone have a better solution, let me know;
Thanks to hpaulj for taking time to help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of a reshape followed by a slice:

```
In [219]: x = np.arange(6)                                                      
In [220]: np.reshape(x,(2,3))                                                   
Out[220]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [221]: np.reshape(x,(2,3))[:,:2]                                             
Out[221]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: My bad, I just understood that I oversimplified my example so your answer is ok but does not match my need. I have edited my question...

Comment: I can't tell what you need.  The examples don't have much in common.